# How I get <b-form-select> element's id ( BootstrapVue) of the options changes event in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to get select's element id on v-on:change event on selected options  in Vue.js

My vue code is :

```
  <b-form-select id="1749614592" :
  options="{'0': 'Default','1': 'Stored'}"
  v-on:change="isOnChange($event)">
  </b-form-select>
```

My script is :

```
   methods: { 
   isOnChange: function(event) {
   console.log(event.target.parentNode);   
   }
   },
```

Comment: From where does <b-form-select> come from? If it is from a component library such as vuetify or element.ui, you should add it to the question. Apart from that, what is the 'tag id'? You mean the option picked by the user?

Comment: You are right, my friend. <b-form-select> related to BootstrapVue.  
I need to get select's element ID on one of the options changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could try the following:

```
<b-form-select 
    id="1749614592" :
    options="{'0': 'Default','1': 'Stored'}"
    v-on:change="isOnChange($event, '1749614592')">
</b-form-select>
```

and as script:

```
methods: { 
    isOnChange: function(event, id) {
        console.log("Selected id: " + id)
    }
}
```